# Type assignation problem in TypeScript (Argument type is not assignable to parameter of type)

Tags: angular, typescript

I've found an interesting Angular 5 project on [Github](https://github.com/ti-ka/ng-workflow) and I'd like to make it work in Angular 14 (I'm using Angular since 1 month, I'm currently learning). Now, since doing it via npm seems a little bit tricky (and I don't even know if it is possible to achieve a good result with it), I was trying to create a new Angular 14 project with all the components and scripts from the code of the repository, and then updating the syntax from 5 to 14.

I "think" that I'm doing it correctly, but I've got an error that I don't really understand. It says:

```
Argument of type 'WorkflowNode | WorkflowConnection' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WorkflowNode & WorkflowConnection'. 
Type 'WorkflowNode' is not assignable to type 'WorkflowNode & WorkflowConnection'.
    Type 'WorkflowNode' is missing the following properties from type 'WorkflowConnection': from, to
```

Here's the code where I have the problem

```
getClickEvent(e: WorkflowConnection | WorkflowNode) {
        if (e.click) {
            return e.click(e); // parameter 'e' is the error 
        }
        return () => {};
    }
```

Here's WorkflowNode:

```
export class WorkflowNode {
    id?: number | string;
    title: string;
    x?: number;
    y?: number;
    click?: (WorkflowNode: WorkflowNode) => void;

    constructor(title: string, id: number | string = '', x? : number, y?: number) {
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

And here's the WorkflowConnection:

```
export class WorkflowConnection {
    from!: WorkflowNode;
    to!: WorkflowNode;
    title?: string;
    fromSide?: 'top' | 'left' | 'bottom' | 'right' = 'right';
    toSide?: 'top' | 'left' | 'bottom' | 'right' = 'left';
    color?: string;
    click?: (Connection: WorkflowConnection) => void;
}
```

Can someone help me understand this message? As I told at the beginning, I found it on Github, I'm not the creator of the repository. I'm just trying to understand if there's a way to make it work with Angular 14. Thanks!

Comment: Given `e: WorkflowConnection | WorkflowNode` you see `e` can be one of these both classes but the connection accepts only a connection as parameter for the click function and the node accepts only a node as parameter. So only objects that look like a connection AND a node are safe to use as param for `click()`. You could make your function generic to solve this problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: @ChristophLütjen ok I understand what you're saying, because the AND (&) is clear in the error. But why is this working in the previous version? What is the difference from 5 to 14?

Comment: @K4lab angular5 project was created on older versions of typescript. I think that's the reason